# New Beta Theme Launched

Tags: discussion

Your site looks a bit different today. Yes, we are getting rid of the 'Sketchy' look and replacing it with a more-polished and finished design for sites in beta.

You can read more about the redesign of our Beta theme on our [blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/).

Please note: This will not affect your "graduation" status in any way. When your site is due for graduation, it will get its final(real) site design and branding.

If you're still seeing the old favicon, please do a hard browser refresh. (Although sometimes it may take Chrome a while to load the new image).

If you see any CSS or styling issues, please report it **[in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126185/new-stack-exchange-beta-theme)** I created on Meta Stack Overflow. It will be easier for me to track all the bug reports there.

Comment: Looks nice, thanks!

Comment: The highlighting of favorite tag questions is horrible. Light yellow on white? Indiscernible.

Comment: Can I say I don't actually like the new look much?  Then again this could just be "shock of the new" style carping and I won't even remember why I didn't like it in a week or so.  Longtime Facebook users will surely know the feeling :)

Comment: It's got visual appeal, but it's a bit... low-contrast in places. I guess it's mostly the various slightly-off-white backgrounds that throw me off; the favorite tag thing mentioned above being an obvious example.

Comment: Now it is much improved! The blue is light and airy but much more readily visible. I have a similar low-contrast complaint about the "Didn't find what you're looking for? Browse other questions..." box at the bottom of the questions (on the main site, not meta). :)